# Quickly access Settings on iOS

Tags: ios, settings

`Settings` can only be accessed by swiping right a few times or entering the `Sett..` and waiting for the app icon to appear? That's really inefficient. So I tried to add it to `Control Center` but it apparently can not be added there either  [Edit Control Center on your iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211812#:%7E:text=You%20can%20customize%20Control%20Center,%2C%20Dark%20Mode%2C%20and%20more.)?

Any thoughts on how to get to `Settings` with just a gesture or two?

Comment: You can set up double-tap to open Settings.

Comment: Why are you needing to access Settings with such rapidity?

Comment: @Allan `iOS` is finicky and my older model / beater phone does strange things frequently. Let's find out how things are configured, but don't make it too much of a hassle to do so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put it in the iPhone's Dock - the set of apps at the bottom which appear in all screens.

[image]

Press and hold any app icon until they all start to wobble, and X delete symbols appear on non-core apps. If your Dock is already full, drag one app out to an empty space on the springboard, then drag Settings in. Press Home to exit edit mode.

<sup>Tested on an old iPhone 5S, iOS 12.5, as comments mention you have an older device.</sup>

Comment: Thx that's what i was looking for, will test in a bit here